# Return code of exec is wrong when using 2>&1 to have the error output

Tags: php, unix, exec

I'm using `exec` to execute some unix commands, like this one :

```
exec('cd /var/www/html/ && export PATH=$PATH:usr/loval/bin/npm &&  npm run dev; 2>&1', $output, $return_code_npm_run_dev);
```

I need to have the output with the error, so I put 2>&1 in the end of the command. But, when I do this, the return code (here : `$return_code_npm_run_dev`) is always 0. When I remove `2>&1`, the return code is what I want (1 if something is wrong, 0 if all is ok.)

My questions are : why `exec` send me `0` when I redirect stderr ? 
Is there another way to have the good return code and the stderr printing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the semi-colon here:

```
npm run dev; 2>&1
```